# Ruby 要素がn個の配列を2つに分ける全ての組み合わせ

Tags: ruby, アルゴリズム

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

このような配列を

```
[1,2,3],[4,5]
[1],[2,3,4,5]
[1,2],[3,4,5]
[3,4],[1,2,5]
```

というように2個の配列に分割したうえでの全ての組み合わせを検討したいです。

```
arr.permutationで行列を計算し、each_slice(2) #arr.sizeが奇数ならば+1
```

等を試してみましたが、上手くできませんでしたので知見をいただきたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
irb> (1..arr.length/2).map{|i| arr.combination(i).map{|j| [j, arr - j]}}.flatten(1)
=> 
[[[1], [2, 3, 4, 5]],                                      
 [[2], [1, 3, 4, 5]],                                      
 [[3], [1, 2, 4, 5]],                                      
 [[4], [1, 2, 3, 5]],                                      
 [[5], [1, 2, 3, 4]],                                      
 [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]],                                      
 [[1, 3], [2, 4, 5]],                                      
 [[1, 4], [2, 3, 5]],                                      
 [[1, 5], [2, 3, 4]],                                      
 [[2, 3], [1, 4, 5]],                                      
 [[2, 4], [1, 3, 5]],                                      
 [[2, 5], [1, 3, 4]],
 [[3, 4], [1, 2, 5]],
 [[3, 5], [1, 2, 4]],
 [[4, 5], [1, 2, 3]]]
```